# scrollHeight is incorrect in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to detect if div has visible vertical scrollbar

But when trying to compare scrollHeight with clientHeight I have scrollHeight is larger by 1

```
   if (div.scrollHeight > div.clientHeight) {
       //div has visible scrollbar
   }
```

Although div don't have visible vertical scrollbar

The problem only with IE.
Chrome,firefox,opera works good

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmwz9/3jnr6/) for my issue

Comment: +1 for providing a JSfiddle! Given Chrome's F12 stats shows figures of 287.2727355957031px and other variations for the different elements, this looks like a rounding error in which case start looking at the styling that affects the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome's F12 stats shows figures of 287.2727355957031px and other variations for the different elements, so this looked like a rounding error in which case start looking at the styling that affects the size.

If you use a fixed height on the table rows the problem goes away, so it is definitely a rounding problem caused by the styling.

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3jnr6/5/

```
tr.SdagItem td {
    height: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a rounding problem. Try

```
style="overflow:hidden"
```

In your parent div. This way the inside table won´t overflow the parent div and the results are as expected.

Comment: I already need the table to overflow parent div to show scrollbar if i set height to parent div